# archiving daily content in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to archive daily content -- in this case analytics.

Every night, an analytics program is run to create a daily snapshot of information for a set of metrics in the following format:

```
object_id INT
metric_id INT
score INT
```

We create a new table, then do a DELETE + RENAME to swap it out.  works perfect.  There can be anywhere from 10k to 2MM rows.

The new concern is that we may decide to one day not just offer the current score, but show scores over time.
We do this for several other sets of metrics, but they are built as needed -- we don't have the raw data needed to recreate these scores again.

I'm leaning towards just archiving everything in a single table like this:

```
object_id INT
metric_id INT
score INT
analytics_date DATE
```

i'm just wondering if anyone has encountered this need before, and has explored using a multi-table format to save the overhead of having a DATE column.

I'm not concerned with the speed of WRITE, as this is a batched job.  I'm mostly concerned with disk space and read performance.

Comment: I would take a look at this. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: The "multi-table format" you describe is table partitioning. It's very common. It has some signficiant downsides in PostgreSQL but is still very useful. Take a look at [the partitioning chapter of the user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm not concerned with Postgres table partitioning (which I am familiar with), but "manual partitioning".  I wanted to avoid talking about "partitions", but maybe should have. Using a partitioned table in PG, I would still have the `analytics_date` column (which would be needed for partitioning). My concern is on the performance/usability of manually created tables, where the `date` can in the table name and not a 4th column.